# Yii2 application distribute data from one database to different databases filtered using a particular field

Tags: database, yii2

I want to do a module that will distribute the data of my application to different databases according to a particular attribute.

Let's say my current program collects employee information and here are the fields that I have:

**db_company**

```
  tbl_employee => [id, fname, mname, lname, name_suffix, birthdate, address, sex, civil_status]
```

Now I want to distribute data according a particular field which is civil_status in different databases with same table structure.

**db_company_single**

```
  tbl_employee => [id, fname, mname, lname, name_suffix, birthdate, address, sex, civil_status]
```

**db_company_married**

```
  tbl_employee => [id, fname, mname, lname, name_suffix, birthdate, address, sex, civil_status]
```

Will it be possible using just a module or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `getDb()` in your model and based on static variable change the connection it returns.

**Config:**

```
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_company_single',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
],
'dbMarried' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_company_married',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
],
```

**Controller:**

```
$model = new Employee();
// Already false but it's easier to get the idea.
Employee::$isMarried = false;

$model->fname = 'Single';
$model->save();

Employee::$isMarried = true;

$model->fname = 'Married';
$model->save();
```

**Model:**

```
public static $isMarried = false;

public static function getDb() {
    if (self::$isMarried === true) {
        return Yii::$app->dbMarried;
    } else {
        return Yii::$app->db;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mate... this gives me an idea.. I will try and let you know know if it works by marking this as correct.. Any idea how can I update the db_company_married once there is an update happened in db_company ???

Comment: You want something like when `Employee` is updated in db_company then automatically db_company_married should update with same data?

Comment: Yes, like when I update employee address in db_company it will reflect also in db_company_married and same goes when I delete an entry in db_company.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to switch [database](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html) connections.

Answer (score 0):

For your case you may need to use master-slave configurations, ad your other database connections to slave configuration, Yii2 Documentation describes it here [Yii2 Master Slave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#read-write-splitting)

**Example code**

```
  [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',

    // configuration for the master
    'dsn' => 'dsn for master server',
    'username' => 'master',
    'password' => '',

    // common configuration for slaves
    'slaveConfig' => [
        'username' => 'slave',
        'password' => '',
        'attributes' => [
            // use a smaller connection timeout
            PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 10,
        ],
    ],

    // list of slave configurations
    'slaves' => [
        ['dsn' => 'dsn for slave server 1'],
        ['dsn' => 'dsn for slave server 2'],
        ['dsn' => 'dsn for slave server 3'],
        ['dsn' => 'dsn for slave server 4'],
    ],
]
```

Comment: I believe slaves ha the same content of master db. Is there a way I can segregate the data by a particular field?

Comment: well, then you need to change the database connection dynamically, depending on your attribute